# FluxMixin error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'store' of undefined" while upgrading to React 0.14.x

Tags: reactjs, react-router, flux

I'm trying to upgrade to React 0.14 from 0.13. I'm getting an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'store' of undefined" in my Application.jsx component (see code below).

Basically `flux` is undefined in Application.jsx from what I can see. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, but I suspect the problem is in the way I'm defining `<Router/>` in `app.jsx`, not passing some property or other, using wrong syntax etc, or has FluxMixin been changed/deprecated and nobody's updated the docs?

Please help.

```
//----------app.jsx---------- This is the entry app point
'use strict';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Router, Route, IndexRoute} from 'react-router';
import Fluxxor from 'fluxxor';
import Application from './components/Application';

let stores = {
    UserStore: new UserStore(),
};

let actions = {
    user: require('./actions/UserActionCreators'),
};

let flux = new Fluxxor.Flux(stores, actions);
let createBrowserHistory = require('history/lib/createBrowserHistory');

let batchedUpdates = require('react/lib/ReactUpdates').batchedUpdates;
let oldDispatch = flux.dispatcher.dispatch.bind(flux.dispatcher);
flux.dispatcher.dispatch = function(action) {
    batchedUpdates(function() {
        oldDispatch(action);
    });
};
const routes = (
    <Route flux={flux} component={Application}/>
);
let history = createBrowserHistory();
ReactDOM.render(<Router history={history} routes={routes}/>, document.getElementById('content'));

//----------Application.jsx----------
'use strict';

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Router, History} from 'react-router';
import Fluxxor from 'fluxxor';
const FluxMixin = Fluxxor.FluxMixin(React);
const StoreWatchMixin = Fluxxor.StoreWatchMixin;

const Application = React.createClass({
    mixins: [History, FluxMixin, StoreWatchMixin('UserStore')],
    // Required by StoreWatchMixin
    getStateFromFlux() {
        return {
            // Getting an error here "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'store' of undefined":
            user: this.getFlux().store('UserStore').getState()
        };
    },
    render() {
        return (
            <div>Work already you bollox!!!</div>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = Application;
```

Comment: Any solutions here? Having the same issue.

Comment: @Karim No, sorry, I couldn't solve it, so upgraded React without upgrading Router, works fine for now.